# C++ syntax: Using a typedef to typecast

Tags: c++, casting, typedef

I am looking over this piece of code, and am having trouble with the syntax:

```
struct Instance
{
    typedef glm::vec3(*OffsetFunc)(float);

    OffsetFunc CalcOffset;

    glm::mat4 ConstructMatrix(float fElapsedTime)
    {
        glm::mat4 theMat(1.0f);

        theMat[3] = glm::vec4(CalcOffset(fElapsedTime), 1.0f);

        return theMat;
    }
};
```

It is C++ code, related to OpenGL, but my question is not about OpenGL. The `glm::vec3, vec4, mat4` are just vectors of dimension 3 and 4, and mat4 is a 4x4 square matrix. The glm library has overloaded operators so lines like:

`theMat[3] = glm::vec4(CalcOffset(fElapsedTime), 1.0f);`

work as you might expect, filling up the 4th column of `theMat` with a 4-d vector that is comprised of `1.0f` and that cast or typedef or function call, I'm not exactly sure what that is, and that is my question.

What does `typedef glm::vec3(*OffsetFunc)(float);` and `CalcOffset(fElapsedTime)` mean?

I tried reading here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef#Using_typedef_with_type_casts , but that explanation doesn't really seem to make sense to me.

Edit: I know how typedefs work when it simply involves providing another alias for a type.

Edit 2: I thought that this might be doing something with a pointer to a function because it kind of looks like a pointer and has `float` in there like its a function parameter type, and it seems like this is the case, but I am still not sure what this kind of code precisely does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef glm::vec3(*OffsetFunc)(float);
```

defines `OffsetFunc` to be an alias for the type `glm::vec3(*)(float)`, i.e. pointer to function taking `float` and returning `glm::vec3`.

```
CalcOffset(fElapsedTime)
```

calls the function pointed to by `CalcOffset` on `fElapsedTime`.

Comment: Yeah, if you ever see this comment: Is it wrong thinking that his use of typedef here is somewhat redundant, since he only uses it once, and its declared inside the scope of this simple struct?

Comment: @newprogrammer: it's kind of redundant because it's used exactly once. Then again, defining `typedef`s for function pointers used at least twice is good practice, because the syntax quickly gets hard to read.

Answer (score 4):

There's no cast. It's a typedef to a function pointer.

The type `OffsetFunc` is a pointer to a function taking a `float` as an argument and returning a `glm::vec3`.

Comment: Yeah, if you ever see this comment: Is it wrong thinking that his use of typedef here is somewhat redundant, since he only uses it once, and its declared inside the scope of this simple struct?

Comment: I don't think it's wrong. Function pointer types are awkward enough that I often use typedefs for them. Defining argument lists that take function pointers without a typedef is both ugly and error prone.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef glm::vec3(*OffsetFunc)(float);
```

is one of the more obscure bits of C (and C++) syntax.

It says that the new type `OffsetFunc` is a pointer to a function which accepts one parameter, a float, and returns a `glm::vec3`.

```
CalcOffset(fElapsedTime)
```

is a function call through such a function pointer:  the function pointer must be set before calling this to point to a suitable function.

Comment: Yeah, if you ever see this comment: Is it wrong thinking that his use of typedef here is somewhat redundant, since he only uses it once, and its declared inside the scope of this simple struct?

Comment: @newprogrammer:  I would not say it is wrong.  When there is a function pointer like that, there are usually assignments to the variable which have to be cast to the same type (at least with the warning level turned up).  So having the function pointer `typedef` declared is a handy way of writing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef glm::vec3(*OffsetFunc)(float);
```

Creates a typedef of a function pointer. The function returns `glm::vec3` and takes a `float` parameter.

```
CalcOffset(fElapsedTime)
```

This is calling the function pointed to by `CalcOffset` with the argument `fElapsedTime`.

Comment: Yeah, if you ever see this comment: Is it wrong thinking that his use of typedef here is somewhat redundant, since he only uses it once, and its declared inside the scope of this simple struct?